# NIntegrate crashes for Interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

I am trying to integrate the output of `NDSolve` over 2D-space and time in the triangular domain that it's solved. It should be straight forward, but I haven't been able to set it up. Here is the code.

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
fksol = NDSolve[{Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][x, y, t] + Derivative[0, 2, 0]  
[u][x, y, t] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x, y, t] + Derivative[0, 1, 0]
[u][x, y, t] == Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, t] + 
NeumannValue[0, x + y >= 1], u[x, y,0] == 
(Erf[x/.1] - Erf[(x - 1)/.1] - 1) (Erf[y/.1] -
Erf[(y - 1)/.1] -1) (PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, .1], x]*          
PDF[NormalDistribution[.8, .1], y] // Evaluate),u[0, y,t] == 0,         
u[x, 0, t] == 0}, u[x, y,t], {x, y} ∈ region, {t, 0, 1}];

Table[ContourPlot[u[x, y, t] /. fksol /. {t -> tt}, {x, y} ∈ 
region], {tt, {0.01, 0.3, 0.5, 1}}]
```

For the integration. I tried to set it up different ways, but nothing is working. I hope someone can suggest me how to set it up. Thanks.

```
pr[x_, y_, t_] := u[x, y, t] /. fksol
NIntegrate[pr[x, y, t], {x, y} ∈ region, {t,0,1}]
```

This gives an error.

```
NIntegrate[pr[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This crashes Mathematica.

Comment: The `fkskol=...` part does not parse, let alone evaluate. So this example needs to be fixed before further investigation.

Comment: That is in essence a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149577/18437) with the addition that this is also time dependent.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I fixed syntax errors, if that is what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this suit your needs?

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
fksol = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][x, y, t] + 
      Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][x, y, t] + 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x, y, t] + 
      Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, y, t] == 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, t] + NeumannValue[0, x + y >= 1], 
    u[x, y, 0] == (Erf[x/.1] - Erf[(x - 1)/.1] - 1) (Erf[y/.1] - 
        Erf[(y - 1)/.1] - 
        1) (PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, .1], x]*
         PDF[NormalDistribution[.8, .1], y] // Evaluate), 
    u[0, y, t] == 0, u[x, 0, t] == 0}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ region, {t, 0, 1}];

Table[ContourPlot[
  fksol[x, y, t], {x, y} ∈ region], {t, {0.01, 0.3, 0.5, 
   1}}]
NIntegrate[
 NIntegrate[
  fksol[x, y, t], {x, y} ∈ fksol["ElementMesh"]], {t, 0, 1}]
0.017628414754904762`
```

This is the same issue as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149577/18437) with the addition that is time dependent.

Comment: Thanks,  this worked in my actual solution. I kind of tried this way too but I didn't use NDSolveValue earlier and got errors. learning it :)