# NIntegrate over eigenfunctions found using NDEigensystem

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method, interpolation, eigenvalues

[image]

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  u[x,y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 10]

trunc = 5;
Table[xt[n, m] = 
  NIntegrate[funs[[n]] funs[[m]] x, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
  {m, 1, trunc}, {n, 1, trunc}]
```

What to do to find the inner product of the eigenstates? It's showing interpolating function.

Comment: Please post actual code, not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying the solution from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152808/75628), you should use the generated mesh of the interpolating functions as the domain of integration.

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 10];

trunc = 5;

Table[xt[n, m] = 
  NIntegrate[
   funs[[n]][x, y] funs[[m]][x, y] x, {x, y} \[Element] 
    funs[[n]]["ElementMesh"]], {m, 1, trunc}, {n, 1, trunc}]

(* {{1.35491*10^-7, 0.287374, 0.16043, 9.83687*10^-7, 
  7.88047*10^-7}, {0.287374, -3.32016*10^-6, -4.19968*10^-7, 
  0.0745046, 0.278054}, {0.16043, -4.19968*10^-7, 
  4.46058*10^-7, -0.27806, 0.0745087}, {9.83687*10^-7, 
  0.0745046, -0.27806, 2.43182*10^-6, -8.28791*10^-7}, {7.88047*10^-7,
   0.278054, 0.0745087, -8.28791*10^-7, 0.0000116938}} *)
```

Comment: I was about to post the same thing when I saw you already answered it. One can verify that integration works by checking this: `NIntegrate[# Conjugate[#], {x, y} \[Element] mesh] & /@ funs` which should give about 1 for a eigenfunctions.

Comment: I have added this as a possible issues item on the `NDEigensystem` ref page.