# How to integrate product of eigenfuctions found using NDEigensystem?

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

[image]

```
\[Lambda] = 2;

g = 1/50;

m = 1;

h = 1;

V[x_] =(*g*(x^2-\[Lambda]^2/(8*g))^2=*)-1/4*\[Lambda]^2*x^2 + g*x^4 + \[Lambda]^4/(64*g);

\[ScriptCapitalL] = -h^2/(2 m)*Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + V[x]*u[x];

{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[\[ScriptCapitalL], u[x], {x, -10, 10}, 50, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05}}},"Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 80000}}];

trunc = 4;

Table[xt[n, m] = Integrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, {x, -10, 10}, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers}], {m, 0, trunc}, {n, 0, trunc}];    `
```

I have used NDEigensytem to solve the Schrodinger equation of the above-mentioned potential. The eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are correct. However, it's not working when I try to measure the expectation value. Why is it not working?

Comment: In your other very similar question you posted a screenshot too. [(261506)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261506/nintegrate-over-eigenfunctions-found-using-ndeigensystem). You must post code, not screenshots of code as nobody will bother typing your code out manually to help you.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Clear[m]
mesh = funs[[1, 0]]["ElementMesh"];
trunc = 4;
Table[xt[n, m] = 
  NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, Element[{x}, mesh]], {m, 1, 
  trunc}, {n, 1, trunc}]
```

You have defined `m` previously, you'd need to start your loop from 1 and not 0 and use NIntegrate as the input is numeric in nature. Also using a mesh is better then the range.

Answer (score 6):

Change `n,m` in your table command! The eigenfunctions are interpolation-objects, though you can use `NIntegrate`:

```
xt = Table[
NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, {x, -10, 10} ,Method -> "LocalAdaptive"],    
{m, 1, trunc}, {n,1, trunc}]

(*{{0.481925, 4.89903, 0.024628, -0.504564}, 
{4.89903, -0.481925,0.504564, 0.024628}, 
{0.024628,0.504564, -0.00243929, -4.75793}, 
{-0.504564, 0.024628, -4.75793,0.00243929}}*)
```