# How to use NDEigensystem to find eigenfuction and Eigenvalues of 1D Harmonic Oscillator?

Tags: finite-element-method, eigenvalues

Where am I wrong? Eigenfunctions and Eigenvalues are coming out fine, but while doing the integration, I am facing difficulties.

```
V[x_] = x^2/2;
 {vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{(-1/2)Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + V[x]*u[x],DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -10^6, 10^6}, 10, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
trunc = 10;
mesh = funs[[1, 0]]["ElementMesh"];
Table[xt[n, m] = NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, Element[{x}, mesh]], {m, 0, trunc}, {n, 0, trunc}];
```

[image]

Comment: What are the errors that you’re running into? This needs more details.

Comment: I have edited my query.

Comment: Table[xt[n, m] = NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, Element[{x}, mesh]], {m, trunc}, {n,  trunc}];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261575/18437) carefully. Iterators like `n` and `m` start from 1, not 0.

```
Table[xt[n, m] = 
   NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, Element[{x}, mesh]], {n, 1, 
   trunc}, {m, 1, trunc}];
```

As a side note, you have an enormous mesh; if you want to model infinite domains, you should have a look at [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) With that you can generate a mesh that is denser around 0 and decays to both ends.